# PHP MAIL <missing_mailbox> (MISSING_MAILBOX)

Tags: php, html, sendmail, sendmessage

i have this php email registration script..but when i receive email doesn't show me html letter.. why ? it show me something like that : Reply-To: no-reply@registration.com

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Thank you for your registration.

```
$setup = "http://127.0.0.1/setup.txt";
$var = file($setup);

// from name
$from[] = $var[1];
// from email
$from_email = $var[1];
// subject
$subject[] = $var[2];
// letter
$msg= file_get_contents("127.0.0.1/msg.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($letter,filesize("msg.txt"));
fclose($lemsgtter);
```

Comment: when i change $var = file($setup); with $var = file($setup, "r"); is ok .. but from_name, from_email and subject it doesn't show nothing...

Comment: give me this : PHP MAIL <missing_mailbox> (MISSING_MAILBOX)